# Will I be sitting on the same plane as someone with the same flight code but different class?

Tags: air-travel

I am travelling using United Airlines and I booked flights for myself and a relative, and wanted to ensure we were both physically sitting on the same plane. I checked the flight codes upon booking but realised afterwards that the flight codes were slightly different: mine was UA 179 K whereas my relative's was UA 179 W. The flight codes are the same (UA 179) but the classes are diifferent (K and W). Will this still mean that we will both be sitting on the same plane? (I have checked other details such as departure time, layover times, aircraft... and they're all pretty much the same). Many thanks.

Comment: If the flight number is the same and it's the same time/date why wouldn't you be on the same plane?

Comment: "[...]  they're all pretty much the same". I'm assuming they are the same, not only pretty much the same..?

Comment: @StewieGriffin pretty much :)

Comment: The fare class relates to the cost of the ticket. It has nothing to do with which flight you're on. For that, you need only look at the flight number, UA 179.

Comment: @phoog UA 179 [is both](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/UAL179) EWR-HKG and HGK-SGN (and they're different aircraft to boot). You'd need more than the flight number to uniquely identify the flight, because obviously it's too simple to have a flight number uniquely identify a flight.

Comment: @ZachLipton true, you also need the departure time, but we know that's (at least "pretty much") the same in this case.  To state my point more specifically: *fare class* has nothing to do with identifying a flight or an aircraft.

Comment: @ZachLipton: If memory serves, flight codes must map to only one plane on any specific day. But don't ask me to prove it...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's definitely not true in the U.S. We'd literally run out of 4-digit codes on the large airlines if we made that limitation. It's even possible to have 2 different planes in the air _at the same time_ with the same flight number. They'll have different callsigns, though. However, on a given day, there will generally only be one flight _originating at a given airport_ with the same flight number.

Comment: @reirab: Fair enough. For good measure, then, I went back to my original "source" to see how well it was backed up, and the answer appears to be "not at all". I was hoping for a IATA or FAA regulation. Ah well. Sorry your airlines are so monolithic and monopolistic btw :(

Comment: @ZachLipton that's a pretty poor example, the flight is one (EWR-SGN), simply made up of two "jumps", obtained with a stop in HKG

Comment: @Federico It was the flight in the OP's question, though. And, as far as I know, all of the flights that use the same flight number on the same day are like that (i.e. A->B, B->C, etc.) At least, I haven't seen unrelated flights use the same number before. In this case, though, it's (very) different aircraft. EWR->HGK is operated by a 777-200, while HKG->SGN is operated by a 737-800.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you will be on the same plane (and in the same section, namely, economy.) As [Berwyn mentioned](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/71831/12011), these are just different [fare classes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45667/12011), both of which are economy fares. The K fare is a cheaper fare class than the W fare.

What appears to have happened is that there were no more seats available in the cheaper K fare class when you booked the ticket for your relative, so their ticket ended up in the somewhat more expensive W fare class. In general, this just means that you paid more for your relative's ticket than for your own. There are a few more small differences, but they probably don't apply to your situation (these are mostly just related to things like upgrade eligibility/priority for people who have elite status with the airline.)

In general, as long as you're on the same flight number on the same date with the same origin city, you are booked on the same plane, regardless of what fare class you have booked (or what class of service you have booked.)

Comment: This means that it is well possible to get seats together if you select them early enough (although I would not wait till checking in if possible.)

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that's true. And I agree on not waiting until check-in to select seats. I always do that as soon as possible.

Comment: @Willeke do you mean waiting till checking on the airport, or checking-in online?

Comment: @Crowley I assume he means not waiting until check-in regardless of whether it's done online or at the airport. U.S. airlines typically allow seat selection at the time of booking (with the notable exception of Southwest, where you select a seat by sitting in it.)

Comment: Indeed, I mean to select seats at first chance. At the time of booking or as soon after as possible.

Answer (score 18):

United airlines booking classes can be seen [here](http://cwsi.net/united.htm).

- K   Deep Discount Coach
- W   Discount Coach

These are different fares within the coach/economy section.