# What is this date on my flight booking refering to?

Tags: air-travel, air-china

I am looking at a flight booking confirmation from Air China, which contains (among others) the following line:

> DEP FRA-FRANKFURT 11FEB SAT 1910 CA 932 MMRFCDE/NW 30JUN 1PC

Now, this correctly describes the flight CA 932 from Frankfurt to Beijing on February 11, and "1PC" indicates the luggage allowance.

However, **what is "30JUN"?** I cannot find any information on the abbreviations "MMRFCDE" or "NW". Is it the period within which the return flight must be taken? The return flights have a slightly different abbreviation there, saying "QQRFCDE/NW", and they indicate a date a few days after the above flight.

There is something like a column header, but it is not quite clear which parts of that line it refers to, and it reads "舱位" - which appears to refer to the luggage allowance (but not sure about that).

EDIT: This is what the line looks like in its original formatting, together with the (badly aligned) column headers:

[image: line of text as it appears in original document]

Note that the line written in Latin script is one word-wrapped line. There are multiple lines with recognizeably the same format across the document, and some have the date still on the upper line rather than wrapping it to the lower line.

Comment: 舱位 is class as in first/business/economy, I don't think that's relevant here.

Comment: The 7-letter strings are likely the fare basis of each leg: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45667/what-does-the-flight-jargon-fare-class-actually-mean-is-it-the-same-as-either

Comment: I would guess NW is the abbreviation of NOW, but the date could be anything, e.g. the price availability date or the date the ticket is valid until.

Comment: @xngtng: For the return flight, the date (assuming the year is the same) is *before* the flight date, though (but a few days *after* the above date for the outbound flight).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Price availability date would be the date until which the fare can still be sold, so that is still possible. But it is hard to obtain a confirmation.